# Referencing the image being touched

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my viewDidLoad function I have a loop creating a 3x6 table of square images (blocks) . The idea is to move and match them eventually.

My question is, how do I assign the current image that is being touched or dragged, as a variable? Here's how I'm adding the image:

```
let squareImg = UIImageView(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "square"))
view.addSubview(squareImg)
```

And here is what I'm attempting to do:

```
@IBAction func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        isDragging = true

        let objectDragging = self.view //this is wrong and what I'm trying to correct

        print("bg color of block being moved \(objectDragging?.backgroundColor)")

 ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the images in an array, assign their index to the tag value, screw touchesBagan etc. and simply use gesture recognizers.

Adding images becomes:

```
var myImages = [UIImage]()

let squareImg = UIImageView(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "square"), tag: [//add a distinguished tag here])
view.addSubview(squareImg)
myImages.append(squareImg)
```

Now that your views are in an array (they don't need to be UIImageViews or even UIImages, just something unique), simply point to the correct thing in your array:

```
@IBAction func handlePan(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        for view in self.subviews as [UIView] {
            if let imageView = view as? UIImageView {
                let image = myImages.tag
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware this isn't exactly what you are asking for. But the technique is. I'll adjust my answer based on your feedback.

EDIT:

Based on the comments, it sounds like a good strategy going forward is to *at least* populate the tag property with "associated pairs in some kind of loop. Additionally, it sounds like some sort of build error is happening. Here's my take on that issue....

Tag properties are available to every object, be they a view or control. Also, they are of Int type. The last comment states the error references an incorrect argument in a function call, expecting an image. I think two separate things are going on.

**(1) Populating the tag property for "associated" images in a loop.**

If you are loading a "square" and a "circle" n number of times, instantiate things in a loop with an index and populate their tag property.

```
for index in 0...10 {

    // instantiate your images

    // associate these images by populating their tag values
    imgSquare.tag = index
    imgCircle.tag = index

    // continue any other set here

}
```

Loop types in Swift are natively Int, so this is correct.

**(2) The incorrect reference build error.**

The build error is on line

```
let circleImg = UIImageView(image: circle, tag: [arrayCounter])
```

This is not a "canned" initializer for UIImageView, and from the build error it's not (yet) a coded extension to UIImageView. It sounds like there *is* a coded extension to UIImageView, one that expects two arguments, *image* and *highlightedImage*. If you want extend UIImageView for something like this, I'd create an extension with a convenience initializer:

```
extension UIImageView {
    convenience init(image: UIImage, tag:Int) {
        self.init()
        self.image = image
        self.tag = tag
    }
}
```

This is a skeleton. You can add a guard statement and make it a bailable initializer. You can add frames, backgroundColor, whatever. The thing is - you currently do *not* have an initializer calling for 'image:tag:' but you are coding for one.

Comment: This is how I should have started off, thank you. Now for the tag, which I'm unfamiliar with, how should I go about that? Because each time through I'm creating a new and different colored squareImg, so do I need each tag to be different? Like a counter variable of some sort? Or is that not what I'm going for with this setup

Comment: That's hard for me to answer. What's the purpose? Is this some sort of game, where there is increasing levels of difficulty or challenge? Or is rearranging the "squares" building something? Even between those you may find handling "tagging" everything "best" something I can't see. A "3x6" array could be easiest done as a one-dimensional array of 18 instead of a two dimensional 3x6 array. Personally? I'd go with storing UIColors instead of UIImages, much less UIImageViews. Tags, which must be integers, would be something like 0 == colors1, 1 == color1, etc. But the details will dictate things.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you are doing (it does sound like something pretty cool though) but from what I glean if you are looking to "associate" various views with each other that may be the best candidate on how to populate their tag property. For instance, if you have six colors among the squares and circles and the object is to move each colored square to it's respective circle, each "pair" or "association" would be a tag value. You might even be able to not need an array.

Comment: I build to the screen the circle, then the square before incrementing my arrayCounter and going to the next set of circles and squares. So I can have the circleImg and the squareImg as the same tag number (just using the arrayCounter variable) seemingly, and store both the squares and circles in their respective array. Then upon moving or dragging, just check to see if the tags match. Would that seem like a logically way to move forward? Swift is saying 'incorrect argument label in call - expected image: highlightedImage rather than image: tag' It wants me to switch tag to highlightedImage

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Throwing an error. I'm having trouble finding documentation on the tag attribute to help myself (http://i.imgur.com/aII005W.png)

Comment: I must thank you. This has made my project a lot easier to work with, so thanks again. Last question. I'm trying to check when my move gesture ends whether or not my objectDragging (which is the tag number in the array) is close to the tag number in the circle array. I have if myBlocks[objectDragging!].center.x == myCircles[objectDragging!].center.x { code.. } but that is way too exact. Is there a way to specify a range? Say, if the x values are within 20, or 10, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. An answer here spoke of how touches are processed, except it referred to UITouch, not UITouchGesture. UITouchGesture has a state property - .began, .ended, etc. That, coupled with coding for a range, should get you what you need. If not, I think that's a very different question than what we started with. Worthy of a new question with specifics, and I would gladly answer. Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
let objectDragging = recognizer.view
```

Comment: That allowed me to build but printed out nil as the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the overrides provided by `UIImageView`.

For Example,

```
class DragImag: UIImageView {
    var draggedView: UIView?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
//here you get your desired view
        draggedView = touches.view
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had fooled around with touchesBegan and moved, but I'm not sure I wouldve implemented that correctly. What do you mean as far as adding DragImg as a subclass to the images? Where would that be done?

Comment: More like assigning a value of type DragImg. For example,
`let squareImg: DragImg = UIImageView(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "square"))`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And I could put this class before my view controller class and then add DragImg as a subclass to my images as you suggested?